# Trigonometry value not match

Tags: c#, math

I want to make a trigonometry function. When I enter the sin function the results don't match, for example sin (30) = -0.988031624092862 (it should be 0.5)

Code:

```
double Sin = Math.Sin(double.Parse(TxtBox.Text));
PreviousValue = Sin;
TxtBox.Text = PreviousValue.ToString();
```

How to handle it?

Comment: From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netframework-4.8): `The angle, a, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert degrees to radians. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.Sin` takes input angle in radian, not in degrees. So you need to convert your input into radian and then pass it into the function.

```
// Converts Degrees to Radian
private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
   return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}

double Sin = Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(double.Parse(TxtBox.Text)));
PreviousValue = Sin;
TxtBox.Text = PreviousValue.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried entering sin⁻¹(0.5) the result is 0.00872675702578704 (it should be 30), but if i try sin(30)=0.5 (it correct)

Comment: Same thing, Sin-1 will return output in radians, not in degress

Comment: i try double SinInv = Math.Asin(DegreeToRadian(double.Parse(TxtBox.Text))); but the result is 0.551069583099446 (it should be 30)

Comment: @Rose: for the inverse functions (like Math.Asin()), you need to convert from radians to degrees, and you need to convert the _return value_, not the value passed to the function.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i try private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
        {
            return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI); 
        }
double SinInv = Math.Asin(RadianToDegree(double.Parse(TxtBox.Text))); but the result is NAN

Comment: @Rose: like I wrote in the previous comment: **_"you need to convert the_ return value, _not the value passed to the function"_** (and it should go without saying, but I'll say it anyway: the value entered in the text box must be a valid sin value, i.e. between -1 and 1, inclusive)